# How to increment state value in PanResponder

Tags: react-native

I'm facing a problem on how to increment the value inside `PanResponder`

Here's my code:

```
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)

const panResponderLeft = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => {
        return true;
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (_, gestureState) => {
        updateLeftPosition(gestureState.dx);
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (_, gestureState) => {
        if (gestureState.dx > 50) {
         setCurrentIndex(currentIndex+1)
        }
      },
    }),
  ).current;
```

Actual output is when I tried to swipe, the value of `currentIndex` updates from `0` to `1` but when I tried to swipe again nothing changes the values retains to `1`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by using this

```
setCurrentIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1);
```

The updated code is

```
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)

const panResponderLeft = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => {
        return true;
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (_, gestureState) => {
        updateLeftPosition(gestureState.dx);
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (_, gestureState) => {
        if (gestureState.dx > 50) {
         setCurrentIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1);
        }
      },
    }),
  ).current;
```